# What does undetermined coefficients guess for $3xe^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find a particular solution of the differential equation $-3y&amp;#39;‘-2y’+y=3xe^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217152/find-a-particular-solution-of-the-differential-equation-3y-2yy-3xex)

I'm not sure how to deal with the $x$ and $e^x$ when multiplied together.

Comment: Uh? What's the question here?

Comment: What does the method of undetermined coefficients guess for $3xe^x$?

Comment: This 'question' is meaningless as it stands. Undetermined coefficients of what?

Comment: @user1038665 We don't know what you're looking at. We don't know what you mean by "guess". You really need to explain things like we were completely strangers. Oh, we are! =)

Comment: I'm not sure what you all mean.  I'm referring to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients

If you look at the "Typical forms of the particular integral," I have the "function of x" as $3xe^x$ and I want to know the "form for y."

Comment: Well, what is your differential equation, to begin with? I see non in the question.

Comment: I'm just asking about $3xe^x$, why do you need to see a differential equation?

Comment: Because the method of "lucky guess" is for differential equations and, in fact, for non-homogeneous ordinary ones?! As it stands, the question is meaningless.

Comment: Looks like the user has made his revision by asking a new question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217152/find-a-particular-solution-of-the-differential-equation-3y-2yy-3xex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you're talking about a differential equation
$P(D) y = 3 x e^x$ where $P$ is a polynomial of degree $n$.
If $P(1) \ne 0$, there will be a particular solution of the form $(c_1 x + c_2) e^x$ for some constants $c_1$ and $c_2$.  If $1$ is a zero of $P$ of multiplicity $k$, then it will be
$(c_1 x + c_2) x^k e^x$.